# Firebase Auth reports 'provider is not enabled' when it is enabled

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase app written in Polymer and I can't use Auth.
It tells me *'Error: The specified authentication provider is not enabled for this Firebase.'* but I have allowed this in the console.
I tried switched the Firebase URL to the one used in the demo and it worked like a charm but when I tried using my URL it doesn't.

Am I using a wrong URL?
My Firebase element is below

```
  <firebase-auth
  id="firebaseLogin"
  user="{{user}}"
  status-known="{{statusKnown}}"
  location="https://teste-firebase-822c4.firebaseio.com"
  provider="{{provider}}"
  on-error="errorHandler"
  on-user-created="userSuccessHandler"
  on-password-changed="userSuccessHandler"
  on-password-reset="userSuccessHandler"
  on-user-removed="userSuccessHandler"></firebase-auth>
```

Is this wrong? **https://teste-firebase-822c4.firebaseio.com**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [current version of the Polymer `firebase-auth` component (1.0.12)](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-auth), is  built for the Firebase version from firebase.com:

> Element wrapper for the Firebase authentication API (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html).

That means it uses the 2.x version of the Firebase JavaScript SDK.

If you created your Firebase project on the [new Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), it will only work with the 3.x version of the JavaScript SDK. You'll need an updated version of the component, which doesn't seem to be available yet.

Comment: Should we migrate to [Polymerfire](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire) on the assumption `firebase-auth` will be deprecated soon?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the plan is to deprecate `firebase-element` and `firebase-auth` and migrate [to the new Polymerfire element](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire).

[Here the relevant Github issue discussion](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element/issues/136).